# My-Domain in Free Trial Org created from Appexchange

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, appexchange, mydomain

We have a listing on the Appexchange that offers a trial option for our ISV product. The trial works and creates the free trial orgs in the correct way.

However, Orgs are generated without my-domain, which is a requirement for our lightning components. We would like to understand if there is a way to generate these free trial orgs with a my-domain already configured.

Thanks!

EDIT 21/01/2020
Apologize me, I have not specified it, the creation of the Free Orgs is done directly from the Appexchange, therefore we do not have custom implementations with the API.

Comment: Is my domain activated at Template Source Organisation?

Comment: Yes it is activated

Comment: @AndreaP. did you solve this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Enable my domain for your trialforce source orgs from which you generate trial orgs.If your TSO has my domain as xyz then your trial orgs will have a domain xyz_1234 where 1234 is the random 4 digits added eveytime a new org is generated from TSO.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately the my-domain on our TSO is active, but on Free-Trial-Orgs it is not automatically generated...
It is not the first time I hear this, so I'll try to contact the SF support